# Align text in Excel cell with new line c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, newline, excel-interop

How can I align the text in Excel when a cell has 2 lines? I tried this:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= RowsCount; j++)
 {
   for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
     {
       ws.Cells[j, i].Style.VerticalAlignment = 
                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
       ws.Cells[j, i].Style.HorizontalAlignment = 
                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
     }
 }
```

But this works only when the cell has 1 line, same like ws.get_range[]...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 points to consider:

**Point 1**

I have noticed that you want to change *vertical* alignment, but you use `xlHalign`. Please try changing that line to

```
ws.Cells[j, i].Style.VerticalAlignment = 
                  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
```

**Point 2**

Try removing `Style`. So you would have something like

```
ws.Cells[j, i].VerticalAlignment = ...
```